# Best way to load multiple TextureRegion from multiple bitmaps in AndEngine

Tags: textures, andengine, texture-atlas

I've seen a lot of examples of AndEngine usage where some bitmaps are mapped into some TextureRegions and loaded into an Atlas. But what if I have a lot of bitmaps, where each bitmap is a sprite sheet, with several sprites for a given entity? How can I extract multiple texture regions from each bitmap and load all that into a single Atlas?